# item index matching by divide and conquer

Tags: c#, .net, search

this is my functions in sorted array to find item index matching but it throws stackoverflow exception

```
static int FindMatching(int[] A, int N)
{
    int high = N - 1;
    int ind = binarysearch(A, 0, high);
    // NOTE: you should return the item itself if exists, otherwise, return -1
    return ind;
}
static public int binarysearch(int[] A, int low, int high)
{
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;


    if (A[mid] == mid)
    { return mid; }
    else if (A[mid] > mid)
    { return binarysearch(A, mid + 1, high); }
    else if (A[mid] < mid)
    { return binarysearch(A, low, mid - 1); }
    else
        return -1;  
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Where does it throw the exception?

Comment: Have you got an Error? Can you clearly define what your looking for?

Comment: Debug the code.  You should be able to see what the problem is fairly easily when actually stepping through it.

Comment: it throws in the recurrsion function it says that make sure u dont have infinite loop or recurrsion

Comment: at least share the stack trace

Comment: @haidy And you almost certainly have an infinite loop.  Stepping through the code should show you under what circumstances you loop forever.

Comment: You are given a sorted (from smallest to largest) array A of n distinct integers which can be
positive, negative, or zero. You want to check whether or not there is an index i that
matches the corresponding item A[i]. If exists, return the item, else, return -1.
Design the fastest algorithm that you can for solving this problem. O(n) solution is not the
most efficient solution for this problem. The required solution is better than O(n).this is the question

Comment: those are the 2 functions where i search for the index and return it but it throws ab exception in the binary search function

Comment: I'm not getting a StackOverFlowException in LinqPad. However I think I found a bug. In the `FindMatching()` method, you're subtracting 1 from N and using that as your high value. Effectively  you'll only be searching the left side of the tree for your provided value.

Comment: @haidy look at my answer, there is more then 1 problem in your code and you design...

Comment: Just for pointing out the algorithm, which I may be providing @haidy with the answer to their homework, [Rosetta Code Binary Search](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search).

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 problem in the code:

1. by the way, binary search isn't good for this purpose. supposed this array:

> 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9

the binary search will say `mid=4 < 9` and search the right side:

> 9, 9, 9, 9

while there is a match in the left side: `A[0] = 0`

2. the last `else` in your code is never reached
3. when the item is never found you will get an exception. you need to add a stopping condition:

   ```
   static public int binarysearch(int[] A, int low, int high)
   {
       if(low > high || (low == high && A[low] != low)) // STOPPING CONDITION
            return -1;
       int mid = (high + low) / 2;


       if (A[mid] == mid)
       { return mid; }
       else if (A[mid] > mid)
       { return binarysearch(A, mid + 1, high); }
       else if (A[mid] < mid)
       { return binarysearch(A, low, mid - 1); }
       else// THIS PART IS NEVER REACHED
           return -1;
   }
   ```

i would change the last part to:

```
        if (A[mid] == mid)
        { 
           return mid; 
        }
        else if (A[mid] > mid)
        { 
           return binarysearch(A, mid + 1, high); 
        }
        else
        { 
           return binarysearch(A, low, mid - 1); 
        }
```

Comment: sry but why the else is never reached ?? when i added the condition the blackscreen dissappears in a second do u ha have solution for this??

Comment: @haidy even though c# is very sophisticated, it is not perfect. it does not recognize that the last 'else if' is in fact equivalent to and 'else' and so it tells you "not all code path return value. but if you change the last 'else if' to 'else' then all is well

Comment: @haidy but again, this is the least of your concerns, did you understood what i meant the the first part of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
static int FindMatching(int[] A, int N, int NoToSearch)
{
    int high = N - 1;
    int ind = binarysearch(A, 0, high,NoToSearch);
    // NOTE: you should return the item itself if exists, otherwise, return -1
    return ind;
}
static public int binarysearch(int[] A, int low, int high,int NoToSearch)
{
    if(low>high || low < 0 || high < 0)
      return -1;

    int mid = (high + low) / 2;


    if (A[mid] == NoToSearch)
    { return mid; }
    else if (A[mid] > NoToSearch)
    { return binarysearch(A, mid + 1, high,NoToSearch); }
    else if (A[mid] < NoToSearch)
    { return binarysearch(A, low, mid - 1,NoToSearch); }
    else
      return -1;
}
```

Comment: sorry but when i run it the blackscreen disappears in a second

Comment: case1:1,4,5,7 output:-1

Comment: I edited your code with NoToSearch, Pass the no you want to search in it. But be aware that your array is already sorted.